# How can I make my customized footer navigate to other pages with swiftUI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm working on a dynamic footer for iOS app and I can't use TabView because it doesn't let me customize the design. I have clickable icons and everything but I am not sure how I can switch pages when those icons are clicked without using the tabItem/tabView functionality.

```
HStack {
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Button (action: {
                            selectedTab = 0
                        }) {
                            Image(selectedTab == 0 ? "white_img" : "yellow_img")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)
                        .frame(width: 1.5, height: 30)
                        .background(.white)
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Button (action: {
                            selectedTab = 1
                        }) {
                            Image(selectedTab == 1 ? "white_img2" : "yellow_img2")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
}
```

The code is just for the first two icons.
I am trying to change the content when the icon is clicked without the footer going away.
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You're not alone trying to implement something like this, here's one attempt that might give you some ideas: https://medium.com/geekculture/custom-tabbar-in-swiftui-4d239410ee73. In general, there's plenty of results in Google for "swiftui custom tab bar."

Comment: replace your `Buttons` with `NavigationLinks` in a `NavigationStack`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine This will push views on top, hiding the bar and everything, will it not?

Comment: I don't now what you are doing, since you don't provide enough code to know. But no, the views will not be on top, they will slide in as new views. Look up [NavigationStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/) and `navigationDestination(...)`

Comment: I want it to go to a new page instead of having the "Back" button on the upper left when I click the icon. Pretty much like how tabView works but without using it..

Comment: you can hide the back button, `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by the combination of **enum** and **switch** statement

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .home
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            switch selectedTab{
            case .home:
                FirstPage()
            case .sleep:
                SecondPage()
            case .meditate:
                ThirdPage()
            case .profile:
                FourthPage()
            case .premium:
                FifthPage()
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            HStack{
                Button {
                    selectedTab = .home
                } label: {
                    VStack{
                        Image(selectedTab == .home ? "HomeS":"Home")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 60,height: 60)
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(selectedTab == .home ? Color("selectedClr"):Color("unSelctedClr"))
                }
                Spacer()
                Divider()
                    .frame(width: 1.5, height: 30)
                    .background(Color.white)
                Button {
                    selectedTab = .sleep
                } label: {
                    VStack{
                        Image(selectedTab == .sleep ? "SleepS":"Sleep")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 60,height: 60)
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(selectedTab == .sleep ? Color("selectedClr"):Color("unSelctedClr"))
                }
                Spacer()
                Divider()
                    .frame(width: 1.5, height: 30)
                    .background(Color.white)
                Button {
                    selectedTab = .meditate
                } label: {
                    VStack{
                        Image(selectedTab == .meditate ? "MeditateS":"Meditate")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 60,height: 60)
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(selectedTab == .meditate ? Color("selectedClr"):Color("unSelctedClr"))
                }
                Spacer()
                Divider()
                    .frame(width: 1.5, height: 30)
                    .background(Color.white)
                Button {
                    selectedTab = .profile
                } label: {
                    VStack{
                        Image(selectedTab == .profile ? "ProfileS":"Profile")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 60,height: 60)
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(selectedTab == .profile ? Color("selectedClr"):Color("unSelctedClr"))
                }
                Spacer()
                Divider()
                    .frame(width: 1.5, height: 30)
                    .background(Color.white)
                Button {
                    selectedTab = .premium
                } label: {
                    VStack{
                        Image(selectedTab == .premium ? "PremiumS":"Premium")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 60,height: 60)
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(selectedTab == .premium ? Color("selectedClr"):Color("unSelctedClr"))
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .background(Color.red.ignoresSafeArea())
            
        }
        .background(Color("bgClr").ignoresSafeArea())
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}

#Preview {
    MainView()
}

struct FirstPage: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("FirstPage")
    }
}
struct SecondPage: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("SecondPage")
    }
}
struct ThirdPage: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("ThirdPage")
    }
}
struct FourthPage: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("FourthPage")
    }
}
struct FifthPage: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("FifthPage")
    }
}

enum Tab {
    case home, sleep, meditate, profile, premium
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `@State` to control the tab and use a `switch` to change the view according. You might want to use two `Spacer()` to ensure that the views will always in the middle.

I would prefer to put all the custom footer into a view  `CustomTabView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)` and pass in the state with a `@Binding`

You can add your `NavigationStack` and `.navigationDestination` here to. So, that all the view can control the navigation. But when control the tab you just need to change the variable like `selectedTab = .home`

```
...
       @State var selectedTab: Tab = .home

        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            switch selectedTab {
            case .home:
                HomeScreen()
            case .screen2:
                Screen2()
            case .screen3:
                Screen3()
            case .screen4:
                Screen4()
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            CustomTabView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
        }
...
```